# Simple Javascript Function Problem

Tags: javascript

This works, with a simple button calling the addDamage function:

```
var damage=0;
function addDamage()
{
damage+=10;
document.getElementById("p1s").innerHTML=damage;
}
```

This doesn't:

```
var damage=0;
function addDamage(who)
{
who+=10;
document.getElementById("p1s").innerHTML=who;
}
```

With this button:

```
<button type="button" onclick="addDamage(damage)">Add</button>
```

It's probably obvious. I'm really new. Thanks!

Comment: what is who? and what's its data type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cheeso has identified the basic problem, which is that JavaScript parameters are passed by value. To get the behavior you want, you can wrap your counter in an object:

```
var player1 = { damage: 0 }; 

function addDamage(who) {
   who.damage+=10;
   document.getElementById("p1s").innerHTML=who.damage;
}
```

Then your button would do this:

```
<button type="button" onclick="addDamage(player1)">Add</button>
```

Presumably you would have other properties for `player1` that you could put in the object as well.

To make the `addDamage` more flexible, you could also pass a second parameter to tell where you want to display the results:

```
function addDamage(who, outputId) {
   who.damage+=10;
   document.getElementById(outputId).innerHTML=who.damage;
}
```

Then button looks like:

```
<button type="button" onclick="addDamage(player1, 'p1s')">Add</button>
```

Answer (score 4):

You are adding 10 to `who` within the function. Via the parameter passed on invocation, `who` takes the value of `damage` which is a global variable.

the function uses the updated value of `who` to set the innerHTML of an element. all that works. Then the function exits.  `who` goes out of scope. The updated value of `who` is now forgotten.

When you click the button again, it uses the value of `damage`, which is still its original value, 0 (zero).  `who` gets that value again, then gets 10+, which is 10, and so on.

---

To update a global variable, return it from the function, and set it in the handler.

```
var damage=0;
function addDamage(d)
{
  d+=10;
  document.getElementById("p1s").innerHTML=d;
  return d;
}
```

and

```
<button type="button" onclick="damage=addDamage(damage);">Add</button>
```

Comment: What I'd like to do is add to the global variable: damage, but be able to reuse the function for multiple different global variables. Am I close?

Comment: @Casey - on right track, but you need to wrap your damage counter(s) in objects. See answer. +1 to @Cheeso for identifying root problem.

Comment: yes, see Joel Lee's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999235/simple-javascript-function-problem/5999324#5999324 . you could also just return the updated value from the func, and set the variable in the onclick. See above edits.

Answer (score 0):

```
var who=0; // want to use who not damage
function addDamage(who)
{
who+=10;
document.getElementById("p1s").innerHTML=who;
}

// also change me from damage to who
<button type="button" onclick="addDamage(who)">Add</button>
```

the nice alternative solution would be this

```
<button id="addDamage"> Add </button>
<div id="showDamage"> </div>

// add handler to button
document.getElementById("addDamage").addEventListener("click", (function() {
    // damage is not stored in global space.
    var damage = 0,
        // div is only gotten once.
        div = document.getElementById("showDamage");
    // show functionality is in its own function so its easily changed
    function show() {
        div.textContent = damage;
    }
    // call show to show the initial damage
    show();

    // return event handler
    return function() {
        // change damage
        damage+=10;
        // show the new damage
        show();
    };
})());
```